# Why does vim still highlight some words after i removed the highlighting

Tags: vim

I have set the bg highlight color to 16(rgb 0,0,0), and most of the words which are misspelled and were highlighted previously were not highlighted anymore, which is what was trying to do.

But some words Still stayed highlighted.

All those words had one thing in common, i.e. They were lowercase after a period(.). I don't find any grammar highlighting option in vim.

I have tried on the internet and... searching this specific case is pretty hard in google.

So, thanks to anyone who helps out.

Here is what i am seeing

[image: the word "of" is highlighted, you might have to squint to see it :)]

Here is what i get when i run

```
function! SynL()                                                                                                                                                                                           
    for i in map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val,"name")')
       exe 'syntax list '.i
    endfor
endfunction
```

On highlighted word

[image: info on highlighted word]

On non highlighted word

[image]

They are the same.

I just want to know, why these highlights are not effected when i change the highlighting configuration (like changing the color(cterm=red)).

Answer (score 1):

to find out what is messing up your syntax you may add this to your vimrc

```
function! SynL()
   for i in map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val,"name")')
        exe 'syntax list '.i   
   endfor
endfunction
```

[image]

then position your cursor on the problematic word and type `:call SynL()`. It will give you detailed info on all the syntaxes affecting the cursor position.

if you'd rather just see the syntax group names affecting the region under the cursor the type this instead

```
:echo  map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val,"name")')
```

[image]

if you install Tim Pope's [scripTease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) than the second option is as simple as typing zS in normal mode

Comment: I tried both the options you gave. and the result i get is same for both, highlighted and non highlighted words. And also, i have only see this happening inside sql comments.

Comment: I don't understand. One should give you an array with the name of the highlight groups that affect the "current word", the other should give you the full info for these same groups. What is the result that you see?

Comment: I've added screenShots of what I get when I run `SynL` and when I run this `echo` command. Does it help you understand what is highlighting your problematic word?

Comment: I meant both highlighted and non highlighted words get the same result.

Comment: I see... If your highlighted word returns the same syntax group as the non highlighted word then, well, I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. Just putting the following info out there, when i make the first character of the word capital the highlighting goes away. Also like i mentioned this happens in sql comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165549/discussion-between-sudavid4-and-adithya-sama).